# Function will output nan instead of a number, why?

Tags: javascript, nan, tofixed

```
<div class="Er3"> 
        <p>  Α </p>
        <form>Input a number <br><input type="n" id="er3">  </form> 
        <button onclick="QuestionThree()"> submit </button>
        <p id="output"> </p>


        <script> function QuestionThree() {
        var y = document.getElementById("er3");
        var o = parseFloat(y);
        var n = o.toFixed(2);
        var x = y - n;
        var z = Math.abs(x);
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = z;
        }</script>


    </div>
```

I have broken the function down as match as possible yet it will still return nan instead of a number, why?

Comment: Which function call returns nan?

Comment: There is no input type called `n` switch it to `number`

Comment: Stop using short variables

Comment: `y` is not a value, it's a DOM element you need to call `parseFloat(y.value)`

Comment: when i pres the button "submit" its seposed to run function QuestionTree yet  all it gives me is a nan results even though i have used parseFloat to turn the string into a number

Comment: Nan means not a number. You're converting object into number not value .you've to take value using geElementById("er3").value

Comment: number input can use use `input.valueAsNumber` might be useful

Comment: Thank you Panjabi it worked

Answer (score 1):

y was holding the element, not it's value. Please try the following code:

```
   <script> 
       function QuestionThree() {
         var y = document.getElementById("er3").value;
         var x = y - parseFloat(y).toFixed(2);
         var z = Math.abs(x);
         document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = z;
       }
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following instruction may help you:

```
var y = document.getElementById("er3").value;
```